# Matching Card Numbers Contitionally

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to verify card numbers using REGEX. All characters must be digits (0-9), if the first digit is 3 the number can either be 15 or 16 characters long, if the number doesn't start with 3, it must be 16 characters long.

Is there a way to use conditional statements in pure regex, not using an external library?

Comment: How about _first_ checking what the first digit is, using the dirt simple `yourString.charAt(0)`, and using that result to determine which method to call to ensure appropriate format validation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make regex conditional using operator `|` (OR)

```
/(^3\d{14,15}$)|(^[^3]\d{16}$)/
```

Comment: This regex matches a string starting with 3 plus 16 digits - 17 chars total

Comment: @AlexRudenko, yes you are right!

Comment: There's worse bug with the number not starting with 3 - it _must have_ 17 chars :)

Comment: This solved my issue, thanks @AlexRudenko, changed the non-3 condition to 15 and it worked perfectly. Only other issue is that strings that don't start with 3 also don't require a digit input for the first character, any thoughts on that?

Comment: @JoshSmith what is allowed then as the first character?  I doubt that _any_ character (including whitespace, punctuation, etc.) may be used in the card numbers.

Comment: @AlexRudenko Only digits should be allowed. Right now, the second condition allows any character that isn't a 3, it should still only allow digits as the first character. (e.g. 'a111111111111111' passes the 2nd condition even though it should only accept '1111111111111111' or any other combination of digits).

Comment: @JoshSmith You may check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64189532/13279831)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with a regexp like this where `|` is used as a logical OR, and intial conditions may be simplified:

```
String regex = "^(3\\d{14}|\\d{16})$";
```

where:
`3\\d{14}` - check the first condition - start with 3, could be 15 chars long (including leading 3)

OR

`\\d{16}` - any digits, strictly 16 chars long

[online demo](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyden896r)

Comment: This was almost what I needed: final string was "(^3\d{14,15}$)|(^\d{16}$)" needed to add the beginning of string character at the beginning of 2nd test condition.

Comment: `(^3\d{14,15}$)|(^\d{16}$)` - here validation of start/end is duplicated and may be moved outside groups; `3\d{15}` is consumed by `\d{16}` but if you like it better that's ok

Comment: That's a good point. Removed the duplicate, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @withrp answer but with `lookaheads`

```
^(?=[3])([0-9]{15,16})|(?=[0-24-9])([0-9]{16})$
```